# Need pagination for following Cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, pagination, nosql, cassandra-3.0

```
CREATE TABLE feed (
   identifier text,
   post_id int,
   score int,
   reason text,
   timestamp timeuuid,
   PRIMARY KEY ((identifier, post_id), score, id, timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (score DESC, timestamp DESC);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_identifier ON feed ( identifier );
```

I want to run 2 types of queries `where identifier = 'user_5' and post_id = 11;` and `where identifier = 'user_5';`

I want to paginate on 10 results per query. However, few queries can have variable result count. So best if there is something like a `*column* > last_record` that I can use.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

P.S: Cassandra version - `3.11.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, and most important - you're approaching to Cassandra like a traditional database that runs on the single node. Your data model doesn't support effective retrieval of data for your queries, and secondary indexes doesn't help much, as it's still need to reach all nodes to fetch the data, as data will be distributed between different nodes based on the value of partition key (`(identifier, post_id)` in your case) - it may work with small data in small cluster, but will fail miserably when you scale up.

In Cassandra, all data modelling starts from queries, so if you're querying by `identifier`, then it should be a partition key (although you may get some problems with big partitions if some users will produce a lot of messages).  Inside partition you may use secondary indexes, it shouldn't be a problem. Plus, inside partition it's easier to organize paging.  Cassandra natively support forward paging, so you just need to keep [paging state between queries](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.6/manual/core/paging/#saving-and-reusing-the-paging-state). In Java driver 4.6.0, the [special helper class was added to support paging of results](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.6/manual/core/paging/#offset-queries), although it may not be very effective, as it needs to read data from Cassandra anyway, to skip to the given page, but at least it's a some help. Here is example from documentation:

```java
String query = "SELECT ...";
// organize by 20 rows per page
OffsetPager pager = new OffsetPager(20);

// Get page 2: start from a fresh result set, throw away rows 1-20, then return rows 21-40
ResultSet rs = session.execute(query);
OffsetPager.Page<Row> page2 = pager.getPage(rs, 2);

// Get page 5: start from a fresh result set, throw away rows 1-80, then return rows 81-100
rs = session.execute(query);
OffsetPager.Page<Row> page5 = pager.getPage(rs, 5);
```